# Unix command to exit from command prompt

Tags: kill, exit, typing-break

How can I exit from command prompt from shell file?

shell file contains :

```
if(); then
// some unix code here
else
// want to exit from cmd prompt or Kill current cmd prompt
fi
```

can any knows @ it?

Comment: At least in GNU bash, have you considered `kill $PPID`? That will kill the parent process of your (script) process, because $PPID is the parent process ID. That said, this sounds like an **awfully bad idea**. At least I would *not* appreciate having my shell yanked out from under my feet, and even less so if I'm logged in e.g. through SSH to a remote host (perhaps having launched a few X applications through it, too).

Comment: It can be helpful for me.. do you know how can i ask question to whether 'you want to exit from command promt or not? in YES or NO' in shell file.  so that i can use your idea to kill parent process. can you tell me the code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Chris Down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72843/2465), I'm going to assume that you are using GNU bash. Other shells may be different, but the general idea should be the same.

In bash, the environment variable `$$` contains the process ID of the currently running process, and `$PPID` contains the process ID of the parent of the running process. As Chris exemplified, you can go even further up, but /proc is Linux-specific.

You can ask the user whether to exit using a construct like the following.

```
echo "Do you want to exit? (type YES or NO, then Enter)"
read answer
if test "${answer}" = "YES"; then
    # insert process killing magic
fi
# we only get here if the user did not answer "YES"
```

If it is available, you can use GNU `dialog` to make the question a little prettier. In that case, replace the entire snippet above with something like the following.

```
if dialog --yesno "Do you want to exit?" 10 50; then
    # insert process killing magic
fi
# we only get here if the user did not answer "YES"
```

The numbers `10 50` specify the size of the dialog box (rows and columns, respectively).

The `process killing magic` could be something as simple as `kill $PPID`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean you want to kill the interactive shell that the script was forked from. I also assume that that shell is `bash`.

If you are sourcing the script in that shell, just use `exit`. Otherwise, send `SIGABRT` (or another signal that will cause bash to exit) to the parent pid (the interactive shell) by using something like this:

```
kill -ABRT "$PPID"
```

Or, in shells without `$PPID` (this is Linux specific):

```
read -r _ _ _ ppid _ < "/proc/$$/stat"
kill -ABRT "$ppid"
```

Comment: @BhushanJ If you found an answer helpful, please upvote it by clicking the up arrow in the left hand column.